# Excel VBA "Compile error: Expected Identifier" for simple cell filling code

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the following Excel macro to fill a selection of cells based on RGB values in separate columns:

```
Sub colour()
Dim R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer, rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Selection
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value2) = True Then
    Else
        R = Cells(cell.Row, 20).Value2
        G = Cells(cell.Row, 21).Value2
        B = Cells(cell.Row, 22).Value2
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Originally the code worked fine but since I have attempted to add an if statement to deal with empty cells I am getting a "compile error: expected: identifier" when I try to run the macro. I am new to VBA and I can't work out what is causing this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This compiles fine for me... do you have any other code?

Comment: This code seems to work, too.  The error must be someplace else.

Comment: `If IsEmpty(cell.Value2)` -> `If IsEmpty(cell)`

Comment: Are you running this on a **Windows** machine??

Comment: @HTH: No. The default property of a Cell (a Range) is `Value`, not `Value2`. This is slightly different (I admit it makes no difference). But I would change the statement to `If not IsEmpty(cell.Value2) Then` and omit the `Else`

Comment: You are setting `rng` as: `Set rng = Selection`. "**Selection**" could be anything at a given point. Try using qualified rang

Comment: Works for me. Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @FunThomas, I see. Just to explain my actual error was not about the default property but the argument type itself: I used the plain `Range` reference because that's what I thought was to be one of the admitted argument type, along with variables reference, i.e. not the Value (be it `Value` or `Value2`). But looking at the MS doc it actually states that _"the argument is a Variant containing a numeric or string expression"_ so actually a range reference would be automatically resolved to its default `Value` property. And hence a `Value` or `Value2` property could do the difference

Comment: This is the only code in this particular model and I don't have any other macros in the project. And yes it's running on Windows 10.